# Changing Language in chrome would not respond

Tags: google-chrome

My chrome browser (Version 74.0.3729.169) is automatically right-to-left in Hebrew even though my system (windows 10) is in English. It is a new Dell computer.

When I go to [chrome://settings](http://chrome://settings) -> languages -> add language, the "Add Language" button simply would not respond.

I even tried to add a command argument "--lang=en" which seemed to have worked several times but mysteriously enough did not last.

I wish to shift to normal Left-to-Right in English

Comment: Does this happen in Chrome incognito mode?

Comment: @harrymc well.. the language is still in Hebrew on incognito mode. but the settings page can not be accessed in incognito mode, even when you type the URL in the incognito mode it will open on a regular mode.

Answer (score 0):

This might be normal, as Hebrew support on English systems is really very sketchy
concerning direction.

I did some testing, and saw that Hebrew text is correctly displayed while
being entered, although this happens only *after* Chrome analyzes it as Hebrew.
Chrome sets itself up as expecting English, Hebrew is only after-the-fact,
and cursor positioning takes some getting used to (I found it very frustrating
when mixing Hebrew and English).

If you have an application that works better in that respect, you might even
need to copy text from it to Chrome. Or use another browser if it handles
this better than Chrome, perhaps installing its Hebrew version.

Comment: Hi I did not understand your answer.. How is it normal that the "Add language" Button does not respond?

Comment: I was talking about the problem of RTL/LTR. I forgot to answer the other problem, which is totally abnormal, for which I suggest to uninstall Chrome, clean up all folders, then reinstall, adding add-ons one by one.